# Angularjs firebase array object always display false

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i having problem when i retrieve data from firebase in console.log($scope.statusbaca) it display 2 query true and false. but when it showing in the app it only display false. Sorry for my bad english. English is not my native language. Hope you understand my problem
[image]
App return false but console log display true and false

and this is my code

**Template**

```
<div ng-repeat= "item in users">
            <div class="list card" style="padding:1%;">
                <div class="col-50" style="float:left;">

                <h5>{{item.displayName}} - {{item.handphone}}</h5>
                <h5>{{item.email}}</h5>  
                </div>
                  <div class="col-33" style="float:right; position: relative;" ng-repeat = "datas in statusbaca">

                    <h5>{{datas}}</h5>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
 var rootRef = new Firebase('https://example-app.firebaseio.com/');
    var childUsers = rootRef.child('users');
    var childDate = rootRef.child('tanggal');
    var rekapId = $stateParams.rekapId;
    console.log(rekapId);      

  childDate.child(rekapId).child('tanggalBaca').once('value',function(snap){

        $timeout(function() {
             var snapshot= snap.val();
            $scope.tanggal = snapshot;       
            console.log($scope.tanggal);
            myAfterFunction();
         });
    })

    function myAfterFunction(){

   var dates = $scope.tanggal;
   console.log(dates);
   var rekapUsers = childUsers.on('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            var key = childSnapshot.key();
            console.log(key);
            var childStatus = childUsers.child(key+'/status/'+dates);
            childStatus.on('value',function(grandsnap){
                var snapval =grandsnap.val();
                $scope.statusbaca = snapval;
                $scope.key = key;
                console.log($scope.statusbaca);
                console.log($scope.key);
              })

        })
        var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();          
        $scope.users =snapshotVal;
        console.log($scope.users);
    })     

    }
```

Any idea what's wrong with my code and how to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix it but your div elements are unbalanced.
You should add a ending div element like this,

```
<div class="col-33" style="float:right; position: relative;" ng-repeat = "datas in statusbaca">

   <h5>{{datas}}</h5>

 </div>
```

Also, I can't find some of the variables referenced by the HTML in the JavaScript and rather than having your
value output like this:

```
<h5>{{datas}}</h5>
```

you should have it like this:

```
<h5>{{datas.THE NAME OF YOUR KEY:VALUE PAIR}}</h5>
```

I can't test it since you're using firebase but, I would do quick run through with your code.